# Create radial network diagram with non-hierarchical data in D3.js

Tags: javascript, json, svg, d3.js, bundle-layout

I am trying to create a diagram similar to this one in D3.js:

http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/bundle.html

This example uses hierarchical edge bundling. However, my data is not hierarchical in nature and I want to represent a relatively simple network structure. I have a bunch of nodes divided into groups, and connected through a simple connectivity matrix. I am able to generate a force-directed network diagram in D3.js similar to this:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

```js
var width = 500,
    height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var graph = getData();

force
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .links(graph.links)
    .start();

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
   .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
   .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
    .call(force.drag);

node.append("title")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
});


function getData() {

return {
  "nodes":[
    {"name":"Myriel","group":1},
    {"name":"Napoleon","group":1},
    {"name":"Mlle.Baptistine","group":1},
    {"name":"Mme.Magloire","group":1},
    {"name":"CountessdeLo","group":1},
    {"name":"Geborand","group":1},
    {"name":"Champtercier","group":1},
    {"name":"Cravatte","group":1},
    {"name":"Count","group":1},
    {"name":"OldMan","group":1},
    {"name":"Labarre","group":2},
    {"name":"Valjean","group":2},
    {"name":"Marguerite","group":3},
    {"name":"Mme.deR","group":2},
    {"name":"Isabeau","group":2},
    {"name":"Gervais","group":2},
    {"name":"Tholomyes","group":3},
    {"name":"Listolier","group":3},
    {"name":"Fameuil","group":3},
    {"name":"Blacheville","group":3},
    {"name":"Favourite","group":3},
    {"name":"Dahlia","group":3},
    {"name":"Zephine","group":3},
    {"name":"Fantine","group":3},
    {"name":"Mme.Thenardier","group":4},
    {"name":"Thenardier","group":4},
    {"name":"Cosette","group":5},
    {"name":"Javert","group":4},
    {"name":"Fauchelevent","group":0},
    {"name":"Bamatabois","group":2},
    {"name":"Perpetue","group":3},
    {"name":"Simplice","group":2},
    {"name":"Scaufflaire","group":2},
    {"name":"Woman1","group":2},
    {"name":"Judge","group":2},
    {"name":"Champmathieu","group":2},
    {"name":"Brevet","group":2},
    {"name":"Chenildieu","group":2},
    {"name":"Cochepaille","group":2},
    {"name":"Pontmercy","group":4},
    {"name":"Boulatruelle","group":6},
    {"name":"Eponine","group":4},
    {"name":"Anzelma","group":4},
    {"name":"Woman2","group":5},
    {"name":"MotherInnocent","group":0},
    {"name":"Gribier","group":0},
    {"name":"Jondrette","group":7},
    {"name":"Mme.Burgon","group":7},
    {"name":"Gavroche","group":8},
    {"name":"Gillenormand","group":5},
    {"name":"Magnon","group":5},
    {"name":"Mlle.Gillenormand","group":5},
    {"name":"Mme.Pontmercy","group":5},
    {"name":"Mlle.Vaubois","group":5},
    {"name":"Lt.Gillenormand","group":5},
    {"name":"Marius","group":8},
    {"name":"BaronessT","group":5},
    {"name":"Mabeuf","group":8},
    {"name":"Enjolras","group":8},
    {"name":"Combeferre","group":8},
    {"name":"Prouvaire","group":8},
    {"name":"Feuilly","group":8},
    {"name":"Courfeyrac","group":8},
    {"name":"Bahorel","group":8},
    {"name":"Bossuet","group":8},
    {"name":"Joly","group":8},
    {"name":"Grantaire","group":8},
    {"name":"MotherPlutarch","group":9},
    {"name":"Gueulemer","group":4},
    {"name":"Babet","group":4},
    {"name":"Claquesous","group":4},
    {"name":"Montparnasse","group":4},
    {"name":"Toussaint","group":5},
    {"name":"Child1","group":10},
    {"name":"Child2","group":10},
    {"name":"Brujon","group":4},
    {"name":"Mme.Hucheloup","group":8}
  ],
  "links":[
    {"source":1,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":2,"target":0,"value":8},
    {"source":3,"target":0,"value":10},
    {"source":3,"target":2,"value":6},
    {"source":4,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":5,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":6,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":7,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":8,"target":0,"value":2},
    {"source":9,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":11,"target":10,"value":1},
    {"source":11,"target":3,"value":3},
    {"source":11,"target":2,"value":3},
    {"source":11,"target":0,"value":5},
    {"source":12,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":13,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":14,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":15,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":17,"target":16,"value":4},
    {"source":18,"target":16,"value":4},
    {"source":18,"target":17,"value":4},
    {"source":19,"target":16,"value":4},
    {"source":19,"target":17,"value":4},
    {"source":19,"target":18,"value":4},
    {"source":20,"target":16,"value":3},
    {"source":20,"target":17,"value":3},
    {"source":20,"target":18,"value":3},
    {"source":20,"target":19,"value":4},
    {"source":21,"target":16,"value":3},
    {"source":21,"target":17,"value":3},
    {"source":21,"target":18,"value":3},
    {"source":21,"target":19,"value":3},
    {"source":21,"target":20,"value":5},
    {"source":22,"target":16,"value":3},
    {"source":22,"target":17,"value":3},
    {"source":22,"target":18,"value":3},
    {"source":22,"target":19,"value":3},
    {"source":22,"target":20,"value":4},
    {"source":22,"target":21,"value":4},
    {"source":23,"target":16,"value":3},
    {"source":23,"target":17,"value":3},
    {"source":23,"target":18,"value":3},
    {"source":23,"target":19,"value":3},
    {"source":23,"target":20,"value":4},
    {"source":23,"target":21,"value":4},
    {"source":23,"target":22,"value":4},
    {"source":23,"target":12,"value":2},
    {"source":23,"target":11,"value":9},
    {"source":24,"target":23,"value":2},
    {"source":24,"target":11,"value":7},
    {"source":25,"target":24,"value":13},
    {"source":25,"target":23,"value":1},
    {"source":25,"target":11,"value":12},
    {"source":26,"target":24,"value":4},
    {"source":26,"target":11,"value":31},
    {"source":26,"target":16,"value":1},
    {"source":26,"target":25,"value":1},
    {"source":27,"target":11,"value":17},
    {"source":27,"target":23,"value":5},
    {"source":27,"target":25,"value":5},
    {"source":27,"target":24,"value":1},
    {"source":27,"target":26,"value":1},
    {"source":28,"target":11,"value":8},
    {"source":28,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":29,"target":23,"value":1},
    {"source":29,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":29,"target":11,"value":2},
    {"source":30,"target":23,"value":1},
    {"source":31,"target":30,"value":2},
    {"source":31,"target":11,"value":3},
    {"source":31,"target":23,"value":2},
    {"source":31,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":32,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":33,"target":11,"value":2},
    {"source":33,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":34,"target":11,"value":3},
    {"source":34,"target":29,"value":2},
    {"source":35,"target":11,"value":3},
    {"source":35,"target":34,"value":3},
    {"source":35,"target":29,"value":2},
    {"source":36,"target":34,"value":2},
    {"source":36,"target":35,"value":2},
    {"source":36,"target":11,"value":2},
    {"source":36,"target":29,"value":1},
    {"source":37,"target":34,"value":2},
    {"source":37,"target":35,"value":2},
    {"source":37,"target":36,"value":2},
    {"source":37,"target":11,"value":2},
    {"source":37,"target":29,"value":1},
    {"source":38,"target":34,"value":2},
    {"source":38,"target":35,"value":2},
    {"source":38,"target":36,"value":2},
    {"source":38,"target":37,"value":2},
    {"source":38,"target":11,"value":2},
    {"source":38,"target":29,"value":1},
    {"source":39,"target":25,"value":1},
    {"source":40,"target":25,"value":1},
    {"source":41,"target":24,"value":2},
    {"source":41,"target":25,"value":3},
    {"source":42,"target":41,"value":2},
    {"source":42,"target":25,"value":2},
    {"source":42,"target":24,"value":1},
    {"source":43,"target":11,"value":3},
    {"source":43,"target":26,"value":1},
    {"source":43,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":44,"target":28,"value":3},
    {"source":44,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":45,"target":28,"value":2},
    {"source":47,"target":46,"value":1},
    {"source":48,"target":47,"value":2},
    {"source":48,"target":25,"value":1},
    {"source":48,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":48,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":49,"target":26,"value":3},
    {"source":49,"target":11,"value":2},
    {"source":50,"target":49,"value":1},
    {"source":50,"target":24,"value":1},
    {"source":51,"target":49,"value":9},
    {"source":51,"target":26,"value":2},
    {"source":51,"target":11,"value":2},
    {"source":52,"target":51,"value":1},
    {"source":52,"target":39,"value":1},
    {"source":53,"target":51,"value":1},
    {"source":54,"target":51,"value":2},
    {"source":54,"target":49,"value":1},
    {"source":54,"target":26,"value":1},
    {"source":55,"target":51,"value":6},
    {"source":55,"target":49,"value":12},
    {"source":55,"target":39,"value":1},
    {"source":55,"target":54,"value":1},
    {"source":55,"target":26,"value":21},
    {"source":55,"target":11,"value":19},
    {"source":55,"target":16,"value":1},
    {"source":55,"target":25,"value":2},
    {"source":55,"target":41,"value":5},
    {"source":55,"target":48,"value":4},
    {"source":56,"target":49,"value":1},
    {"source":56,"target":55,"value":1},
    {"source":57,"target":55,"value":1},
    {"source":57,"target":41,"value":1},
    {"source":57,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":58,"target":55,"value":7},
    {"source":58,"target":48,"value":7},
    {"source":58,"target":27,"value":6},
    {"source":58,"target":57,"value":1},
    {"source":58,"target":11,"value":4},
    {"source":59,"target":58,"value":15},
    {"source":59,"target":55,"value":5},
    {"source":59,"target":48,"value":6},
    {"source":59,"target":57,"value":2},
    {"source":60,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":60,"target":58,"value":4},
    {"source":60,"target":59,"value":2},
    {"source":61,"target":48,"value":2},
    {"source":61,"target":58,"value":6},
    {"source":61,"target":60,"value":2},
    {"source":61,"target":59,"value":5},
    {"source":61,"target":57,"value":1},
    {"source":61,"target":55,"value":1},
    {"source":62,"target":55,"value":9},
    {"source":62,"target":58,"value":17},
    {"source":62,"target":59,"value":13},
    {"source":62,"target":48,"value":7},
    {"source":62,"target":57,"value":2},
    {"source":62,"target":41,"value":1},
    {"source":62,"target":61,"value":6},
    {"source":62,"target":60,"value":3},
    {"source":63,"target":59,"value":5},
    {"source":63,"target":48,"value":5},
    {"source":63,"target":62,"value":6},
    {"source":63,"target":57,"value":2},
    {"source":63,"target":58,"value":4},
    {"source":63,"target":61,"value":3},
    {"source":63,"target":60,"value":2},
    {"source":63,"target":55,"value":1},
    {"source":64,"target":55,"value":5},
    {"source":64,"target":62,"value":12},
    {"source":64,"target":48,"value":5},
    {"source":64,"target":63,"value":4},
    {"source":64,"target":58,"value":10},
    {"source":64,"target":61,"value":6},
    {"source":64,"target":60,"value":2},
    {"source":64,"target":59,"value":9},
    {"source":64,"target":57,"value":1},
    {"source":64,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":65,"target":63,"value":5},
    {"source":65,"target":64,"value":7},
    {"source":65,"target":48,"value":3},
    {"source":65,"target":62,"value":5},
    {"source":65,"target":58,"value":5},
    {"source":65,"target":61,"value":5},
    {"source":65,"target":60,"value":2},
    {"source":65,"target":59,"value":5},
    {"source":65,"target":57,"value":1},
    {"source":65,"target":55,"value":2},
    {"source":66,"target":64,"value":3},
    {"source":66,"target":58,"value":3},
    {"source":66,"target":59,"value":1},
    {"source":66,"target":62,"value":2},
    {"source":66,"target":65,"value":2},
    {"source":66,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":66,"target":63,"value":1},
    {"source":66,"target":61,"value":1},
    {"source":66,"target":60,"value":1},
    {"source":67,"target":57,"value":3},
    {"source":68,"target":25,"value":5},
    {"source":68,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":68,"target":24,"value":1},
    {"source":68,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":68,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":68,"target":41,"value":1},
    {"source":69,"target":25,"value":6},
    {"source":69,"target":68,"value":6},
    {"source":69,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":69,"target":24,"value":1},
    {"source":69,"target":27,"value":2},
    {"source":69,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":69,"target":41,"value":1},
    {"source":70,"target":25,"value":4},
    {"source":70,"target":69,"value":4},
    {"source":70,"target":68,"value":4},
    {"source":70,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":70,"target":24,"value":1},
    {"source":70,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":70,"target":41,"value":1},
    {"source":70,"target":58,"value":1},
    {"source":71,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":71,"target":69,"value":2},
    {"source":71,"target":68,"value":2},
    {"source":71,"target":70,"value":2},
    {"source":71,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":71,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":71,"target":41,"value":1},
    {"source":71,"target":25,"value":1},
    {"source":72,"target":26,"value":2},
    {"source":72,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":72,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":73,"target":48,"value":2},
    {"source":74,"target":48,"value":2},
    {"source":74,"target":73,"value":3},
    {"source":75,"target":69,"value":3},
    {"source":75,"target":68,"value":3},
    {"source":75,"target":25,"value":3},
    {"source":75,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":75,"target":41,"value":1},
    {"source":75,"target":70,"value":1},
    {"source":75,"target":71,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":64,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":65,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":66,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":63,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":62,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":58,"value":1}
  ]
}

}
```

```css
.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

However, I can't figure out how to generate the radial graph above when the structure is not hierarchical. In the example given here

https://gist.github.com/mbostock/7607999

[image]

they use the bundle() and cluster.nodes() functions which require a hierarchical data structure. Can I use the same json data structure that I use for the force-directed graph for this type of radial graph? If yes, how?

EDIT: Here is a (non-working) JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/12sb8jxg/

I added

```
nested = d3.nest()
.key(function (d) {
return d.group;
})
.entries(graph.nodes);
```

but

```
cluster.nodes(nested)
```

still doesn't append the .x, .y, .parent etc. necessary for the bundle function to work.

Comment: You could use D3's [nesting](http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/) to convert your data to a hierarchical structure based on the groups.

Comment: Hmm, with this particular data it isn't quite as easy unfortunately. You'll need to add nodes for the top-level groups as well, which you can't do (easily) with nesting.